Populate 2nd Select2 from Selections on 1st Select2 with AJAX and OptGroup
I have my first select2 that I pull data into from remote ajax search with multiple options allowed:
$("#EmailSentToGroup").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/trip-search",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                q: params.term 
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            var resData = [];
            data.forEach(function(value) {
                resData.push(value);
            })
            return {
                results: $.map(resData, function(item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.TripName,
                        id: item.Id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
        //,cache: true
    },
    placeholder: "Select Trip(s)...",
    minimumInputLength: 3
})

with data return like this:
[
   {"id":"123","TripName":"Trip Name 1"},
   {"id":"456","TripName":"Trip Name 2"},
   {"id":"789","TripName":"Trip Name 3"}
]

I then have a second select2 that I want to populate based on the selection(s) that are in the first select2.  I initialize like this on ready: $("#SelectPackages").select2();
onchange or onselect of the first select2, I want the data to be updated in the second.  I want to have optgroups to be able to group my data returned by trip for ease of viewing.
$('#EmailSentToGroup').on('change select', function() {
    updatePackages();
});

Now updatePackages is like this, the part for processResults or success is what I cannot figure out.

The format of the JSON response
How to process these results into meaningful data select2 can understand & display.

function updatePackages(){
   $("#SelectPackages").select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "/data/trip-packages-lists?ids=" + $("#EmailSentToGroup").val(),
        type:     "POST",
        dataType: "json'",
        processResults: function (data) {
          //THIS IS THE PART I CANNOT FIGURE OUT!!!
        }
      }        
  });
}

I have seen some of the other similar posts, but they do not add in the other complexities I am trying to do.  (https://forums.select2.org/t/populatate-a-second-select-based-on-selection-a-1st-select/472/3)
any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent the better part of a day on this already!
Thank you.

After posting this, it became clearer to me that I had part of my answer already in my first call that was working, so I updated UpdatePackages() to this:
    $("#EmailSentToGroup").on("change select", function() {
        $("#SelectPackages").val(null).html("").trigger("change");
        updatePackages();
    });

    function updatePackages(){
        $.getJSON( "/trip-packages-lists?type=packages&ids=" + $("#EmailSentToGroup").val(), function(respond) {
            $("#SelectPackages").select2({
                multiple: true,
                data: respond
            });
            });
        
        /*
        $("#SelectPackagesXX").select2({ //Do not use this since it will call Ajax each time you type in newly popualted select2
            ajax: {
                url: "/trip-packages-lists?type=packages&ids=" + $("#EmailSentToGroup").val(),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function(params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    }
                }
            }        
        });
        */
    }

and this is the ajax response for those that cannot find this example like I could:
[
    {
    "text": "Trip Name 1",
    "children": [
        {"id": "2278","text": "A) Package 1"},
        {"id": "2279","text": "B) Package 2"}
    },
    {
    "text": "Trip Name 2",
    "children": [
        {"id": "4159","text": "Trip Package 1"},
        {"id": "4160","text": "Trip Package 2"},
        {"id": "4158","text": "Trip Package 3"}
    ]}
]

And this page helped me understand how to process the results with optgroups via json format.
How to add this optgroup json data to Select2?
and
Populate Select2 with AJAX data
